# Dips and pushups in the same week?

Tags: push-ups, chest, bodyweight, calisthenics, dips

My routine on triceps and chest workout, as of now, is: every first week — pushups twice and dips once; every other week — vice versa.

I can't do dips and pushups in the same day, so basically, that is three days in a week working on my triceps and chest. Is this too much work for these muscles? Should I start doing both pushups and dips only once a week?

Comment: How many dips/push ups can you normally do / want to do for your routine? Is this a home workout and you don't have access to assisted dips/elastic bands to help you?

Comment: What is 'pushups twice' ? One set of X reps or Y sets if X reps 2 times a week?

Comment: I usually do chest and dips on the same session, why separate them (or maybe you are not strong enough yet)? Anyway, don't train your pecs/triceps too much, train your legs !

Comment: @JJosaur I currently go for that high sets and high reps training, so I usually do around 12 sets of pushups, but not only the normal full pushups — I do sets of all uneven, diamond, decline and full pushups and that totals to around 12 sets (of 10-20 reps). So, pushups are in my workout twice a week. I separate them because of that high sets type of workout, so I can't do 12 sets of pushups and then proceed to more sets of dips — that seems like too much for my triceps. Plus, yeah, I don't even have access to dipping bars at my home (home is where I exercise). akadian

Comment: @boris I do train my legs a lot, btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do them on the same day.

There's no way why you should restrain on doing them. You just have to manage your total workload based on how you feel physically and mentally or based on your overall periodization regimen.